# Any good examples/references implementing ACLs via SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, acl

I currently have a web-application that implements a rudimentary form of ACL using UNIONs in mysql, but it's somewhat limited, and doesn't necessarily scale that well

I'm interested in any alternative ACL algorithms that could be implemented efficiently in SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this document as a model for implementing row level security in a Sql Server based CRM system.  In my implementation, rows are made available to a given user based on their Active Directory group memberships.

The performance was surprisingly good when appropriately indexed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx

Comment: I'll have a look at translating this logic to more generic mysql... but thanks!

Comment: No one came up with an answer that's suitable for mysql but I think this should give me enough to build my own solution, which I will post here when I do for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @FilmJ How's that coming along? :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for unix like file permissions in sqlite, which I wrote. I do not know however how performant it ist:

https://github.com/orgesleka/unix-acl-sql